# LINQ with List<object>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to fetch few rows with db.

With this code, I get one specific row.

```
int mid =1;
ClassA obja = Obj1.exp.Values.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == mid);
ClassB objb = Obj1.Pol.Values.FirstOrDefault(i => i.GId == obja.MGId);
```

BUt, I want to have a list of rows, basically remove FirstorDefault to List. How can I do that ?

```
List<ClassA> l_obja = Obj1.exp.Values.Where(i => i.Id == mid).ToList();
List<ClassB> l_objb = Obj1.Pol.Values.Where(i=> l_obja.Contains(i.MGId)); // Get all rows where l_obja.MGID = i.MGID
```

I tried this, but it does not work
Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: "but it does not work" isn't a  problem description.. What doesn't work? do you get an unexcpected result? an exception? what? where is the details?

Comment: I get a compilation error in the last line. `list<classB>.`

Comment: What compilation error :) We have no idea what your rest of code/classes/db etc. are. Try to learn how to ask a good question.... Most propably, because of `Where` doesn't return a list. IEnumerable? IQuerable? Have you tried to use simply a `var` instead of `List<ClassB>` ?

Comment: See the answer by juharr. You will understand little bit.

Comment: mr demo. some smart guy's posting good answer doesn't make your question good too :) **-1**

Comment: You understand the question, so atleast you can help some other person if he has some problem. If you cant solve it, wait for few minutes for some smart person to answer.

Comment: mr demo.  Seems like you don't get what **-5** means... 5 people think that your question is *poor*. BTW: What is the problem with you? what is so hard in saying that, "OK I'll read SO docs about how to ask a good question and next time I'll try to ask a more complete question"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `Any` for that since `l_obja` is not a list of the ids.

```
List<ClassA> l_obja = Obj1.exp.Values.Where(i => i.Id == mid).ToList();
List<ClassB> l_objb = Obj1.Pol.Values.Where(i => l_obja.Any(a => a.MGId == i.GId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ClassB> l_objb = Obj1.Pol.Values.Where(i=> l_obja.Contains(i.MGId)).ToList();
```